# Block single apk notifications via adb

Tags: android, apk

I'm looking to change notifications settings for a single application remotely.
I've got the device enrolled into a MDM.
Android device running 6.01.

I can remotely deploy / update apps etc...
However, I want to disable notifications for this.  I can't seem to find a hands off approach to doing this.

I'd have to break out of the end user lock down application.
Go to settings
apps
find app
notifications
block
restart device.

Is there a way I can remotely make this change?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you might have more luck asking your MDM provider but there is no way to achieve this from the platform.  This is not a requirement I have heard before, typically enterprise devices are configured to block all notifications or allow all.  If you do not plan on using the application in question you could likely disable the entire app remotely but being able to disable notifications for that specific app remotely is not currently possible.

Comment: Thank you for responding. The MDM provider said it was an OS behavior and needs to be suppressed from the OS.  I got it sorted by disabling them the manual way.

Answer (score 0):

The MDM provider said it was an OS behavior and needs to be suppressed from the OS. I got it sorted by disabling them the manual way.